# How to make a div stick to bottom of Drawer with same width of the Drawer React Material UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I make a `Drawer` at right hand side using `<Drawer/>` , I want 1 `<div>` is stick to the bottom of the `<Drawer />`  ,at the same time , the width of the `<div>` will same with the `<Drawer />` .

Desired outcome:

[image]

This is what I tried to achieve the outcome above:

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles({
  list: { // <-- this set the width of Drawer
    width: 500,
  },
  bottomContainer: {
    position: "fixed",
    bottom: 0,
    display: 'flex',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: '30px'
 },
});
```

But when I set the `position:fixed` ,the bottom div become like this:

[image]

As you can see, the whole div is gel together, and not match the width of drawer. But if set `position: relative` ,the `bottomContainer` appear same width `div in top` and display below it, but not bottom of the `<Drawer />` .

If I set `width: '100%'` to `bottomContainer`, the `Abc` appear outside of the `<Drawer />`

**Therefore my question is:**

How to make a `<div>`  with same width with `<Drawer/>`  and appear at the bottom of the `<Drawer />`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **flexbox** in this case.

You should set a container which contains a height and both child elements. By adding `display: flex`, `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: space-between`.

In the second div which contains two paragraph elements, you add another `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between`. You don't need to add `flex-direction` here since the default is `flex-direction: row`. You can also add `align-items: center` here to vertically center align the content.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.div1, .div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>abc</p>
    <p>123</p>
  </div>
</div>
```